# Naming and adding css variables to vue projects

Tags: css, vue.js, variables

I would like to hear others opinion about variables used in CSS.
In my vue projects I declare variables for :root and then use var to add them to the desired css properties. I also use scss in my projects, but I don't think it doesn't cancel the possibility to use standard variables.
I started to notice that in some of the projects these variables are getting to be a lot. Maybe 30-40 at least. Also the problem is that by agreement with the others working on the projects, we share variables for background, text color, etc.
Thus, variables can also appear in the end:
--app-primary-background: #000000;
--app-primary-color: #000000;
This is where I wondered: is it normal to leave it like this or suggest others to reduce the number of variables and remove duplicates.
That's why I want to ask others, how do you use variables in projects in general? Do you try to add only one variable for one color or can you still allow duplicates for background, text color and other parts?
I'm also curious, how do you name these variables? Sometimes there can be only 10-12 background colors in a project and I think naming them in this style is not very good:
--app-background-primary-color
--app-backgound-second-color.
--app-backgroud-third-color
--app-background-fourth-color
--app-background-fifth-color

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.